# Beeping smoke alarm

Tags: electrical

How can we stop our electric smoke alarm on the ceiling of our stairwell

to stop beeping it usually happens when it's very cold out and we turn on our heat inside along with wood stove

Comment: Have you tried changing the battery?

Comment: How old is the alarm? They have a limited life.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the battery doesn't solve the problem, then either the smoke alarm is malfunctioning, or else one or more of your heating appliances is malfunctioning and letting dangerous combustion byproducts into your house. First replace the smoke alarm (they're cheap, but keep the box and receipt). If the new one beeps, then return it and have your combustion appliances checked out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before:

- Check battery.
- Change units.

If you are still having a problem and you don't have combustion products as a cause, then one of the following may be an issue:

- Humidity from a shower/kitchen area in cold weather is condensing in the alarm causing a fault.
- The wood stove is pulling air into the house through the box in the stairwell.  This is chilling the box, and creating moisture.
- The heat from the wood stove is creating thermal drafts that are tripping the alarm.

I've lived with smoke alarms and wood stoves for some time.  Rather than having constant false alarms everytime a puff of smoke got into the room, I now mount my alarms  on the wall just above door height.

This is not code.  It means that it may take a few more seconds for the alarm to go off.  I considier this a smaller issue than people rolling over, "another false alarm"

Answer (score 0):

Older smoke detectors (and some new ones) use ionization to detect a fire. This can produce some false alarms like this.

Some newer smoke detectors use [optical sensors to detect smoke](http://www.safelincs.co.uk/smoke-alarm-types-optical-alarms-overview/)

[image]

This might work better for you

Answer (score 0):

**This is a low-battery warning and may be caused by the cold temperature.** (I assume that "beeping" means an intermittent "chirp".)

A cold battery has higher internal resistance, and thus a lower available voltage, than a warm battery. The smoke detector may interpret the decrease in voltage as a low battery.

Try using a different battery chemistry or moving the detector to a warmer part of the room.

Answer (score 0):

The US National Institute of Standards and Technology has a [great executive summary of their fire study on smoke alarms](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/el/fire_protection/buildings/ExecSummaryfromNIST_TN_1455-1_Feb2008.pdf).

> As expected, CO
>   alarms respond best to fires which produce considerable quantities of carbon monoxide during
>   the combustion process, i.e., smoldering fire scenarios and the closed-door flaming mattress
>   (which smoldered after the room of fire origin became oxygen limited).

You mentioned a wood stove, so I quote above comments on carbon monoxide from smoldering fires, which may be an issue with getting a wood fire started. Check the type of the alarm. If it's a CO alarm, that's a definite cause for concern and may indicate early warning levels for your alarm that don't reach levels for full alarm. You don't mention visible smoke, so it's likely to an ionization or CO alert - if not the low battery alert from the cold mentioned by another answer.

Your question isn't directly on which fire alarms you **should** have and where, but the summary I've linked to covers ionization, optical, and carbon monoxide detectors. In other materials, there are specific recommendations on where in the dwelling to place them, where on the wall/ceiling for proper activation, and replacement guides. Most alarms have an expected 10 year life cycle, and - at least in the US - many now come with a sealed non-replaceable battery.  When it starts to chirp, it's time to replace it.

As a last public service comment, [closing bedroom doors to sleeping areas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-cQKlT1SlI) can significantly increase your opportunity to escape a fire by reducing flow of smoke/gasses into sleeping areas.

Comment: Thanks, @ThreePhaseEel, for the edit. Had Safety on the brain.